# LDAP store SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, ldap, certificate, opends

I'm using OpenDS as a LDAP server. Is it possible to store SSL certificates for several applications (Tomcat/Apache Webserver etc.) in LDAP?

I think "userCertificate" wouldn't be the right choice. Could this be handled by an extension?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Follow up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414640/how-to-store-keystore-using-userpkcs12-in-ldap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the purpose.

- `userCertificate` is for certificates
- `userPKCS12` is for PKCS12 keystores including key-pairs, certificates, and signer chains.

One object class that includes them both is `inetOrgPerson.`

Comment: Alright. If I have this entry

`dn: cn=Tomcat,ou=ApplicationContext,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: applicationEntity
supportedApplicationContext: Java
presentationAddress: /opt/Tomcat
cn: Tomcat`

I just have to add:

`userCertificate: certificate information`

Right?

Comment: Right if `applicationEntity` supports that attribute. Otherwise you'll have to use an object class that does, or add a mix-in object class to this entry that supports `userCertificate' l I found one yesterday but I can't remember what it is. I don't see why you would want to store certificates with Tomcat but not keys.

Comment: Just to add the name of the auxiliary class that contains the `userCertificate attribute is `pkiUser`.

Comment: @ZoranRegvart Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @EJP and @ZoranRegvart for your helpful answers. During installation of Tomcat (using a shell script) the keystore is generated automatically. I just want to store the certificate because I want other tomcats to query LDAP for this certificate and then importing it to **their** truststore. `applicationEntity` doesn't have the  certificate attribute but maybe I will just add a new object class with all attributes of `applicationEntity` and the `userCertificate` attribute